# Creating the layer functionality in Flash CS5 (as3)

Tags: actionscript-3

Hi I need to create the application in Flash CS5 with the help of as3 where the  user can draw according to his requirement but in layers. This app will provide user to create Business Cards, Broushers etc. Can anyone help me in create the layer functionality. Only the layer functionality of this app is remaining. If anyone one can resolve it please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you are looking for requires a lot of development time.
The basic idea is to create a stack of sprites and draw on each one of them the shapes or images that you need. Last year I build an application just like that and it took several month to finish.
If you want to build it yourself you should ask much more specific question on how to do things.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat each layer as a sprite and draw into these sprites using the graphics object of each, you can easily change the ordering of the layers by changing the indices of the sprites in the container they are in.

```
var layer1:Sprite = new Sprite();
container.addChild(layer1);
var layer2:Sprite = new Sprite();
container.addChild(layer2);

layer1.graphics.***  //drawing functions
layer2.graphics.***  //drawing functions

container.setChildIndex(layer1,1);  //change ordering
```

Hope that helps.